# Send ClaimCollection from Silverlight to WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, azure, adfs

I am implementing ADFS for a Silverlight application hosted in the cloud. I am using the Identity model provided in the IdentityTrainingKit to read the claims using Passive Authentication. I am successfully getting all the claims from the STS server in my silverlight. Now, I want to send that ClaimCollection to a WCF service from the silverlight application.

Can you please help me by providing some samples codes, aricles etc on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that that WCF service is part of your application.  In that case, it is not necessary to send the claims from the client to the WCF service.  When a user accesses your Silverlight-based application, first the WIF-based web application (so the server side which hosts the Silverlight component(s)) receives the claims from AD FS, and WIF makes them available by returning an [IClaimsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.iclaimsidentity.aspx) or [IClaimsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.iclaimsprincipal.aspx) whenever the current [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx) or [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) is requested; see for example [WIF's "Integration with IIdentity and IPrincipal"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748503.aspx).  [IClaimsIdentity.Claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.iclaimsidentity.claims.aspx) then gives you the ClaimCollection.

If the WCF service is a separate service, then it is very difficult to call it from the Silverlight client: the Silverlight version of the .NET framework does not contain enough to support calling a claims-based web service.  (It is apparently possible but very convoluted; I could look up the details if desired.)  But why not call that WCF service from the *server* side of your application?  That is a standard pattern.  (Again, I don't know the details but could look them up.)

Comment: In that case.....how can I send the token received from a STS to the WCF. That is, suppose my silverlight/asp.net app received the bootstrap token, how can I attach the token to the subsequent call to my local WCF. The WCF should be able to decrypt and read its claim collection.